# Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, wget, https

When I try to download the package from [this link](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/wget-list) I get a error; 
In curl;

```
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

In wget;

```
--2020-10-27 19:17:40--  https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/wget-list
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving www.linuxfromscratch.org (www.linuxfromscratch.org)... 192.155.86.174, 2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe70:25e8
Connecting to www.linuxfromscratch.org (www.linuxfromscratch.org)|192.155.86.174|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Chromium Browser;

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

www.linuxfromscratch.org sent an invalid response.


ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

---

Operating system: Fresh Arch Linux Latest Installation

Comment: Looks like the site is broken.

Comment: This site currently only provides HTTP without TLS, even on port 443 it tries to speak HTTP instead of HTTPS: `http://www.linuxfromscratch.org:443` It shows an Apache default page.

Comment: Yes, I tried http protocol and it worked.